# How can I switch from orchestrate.io db to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I recently followed a tutorial to create a node.js server connecting to orchestrate.io database. The problem is I now want to point the server at a mongodb hosted on mongolab - currently I am declaring a variable:

```
var db = require('orchestrate')(APIKEY);
```

which allows me to retrieve data using something like:

```
db.get('collection', key)
.then(function(result){

    console.log(result.body);

});
```

My question is - Is there any way I can switch the value of 'db' to point at a mongolab database without changing the structure of the get request?

Answer (score 0):

I work at Orchestrate and [we do not believe in data lock-in](https://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/02/05/data-lock-in-a-qa-with-orchestrate-cto-ian-plosker/). I hope you'll reconsider using our service, but here's some advice if you choose to leave...

It sounds like your code is fairly minimal, so you may be best off recreating your Node server with another tutorial specific to Mongo.

That said, if you are using simple key-value storage, it should be as easy as rewriting the db.get Orchestrate lines to be [db.find functions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) from MongoDB. If you've loaded a lot of data you could [export it](https://orchestrate.io/docs/data-export) from Orchestrate, then import into Mongo (either manually, or using another tool).

If you're using some advanced, built-in Orchestrate features, such as full-text search, relation graphing, time-series data, and geographic look-ups, it may take some more effort (and MongoDB experience) to switch. If you'd like these features in a highly scalable database-as-a-service that you don't have to maintain, you know where to find us.